# Where can I find the TLD docs for the html and core tags for JSF2.0

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I am moving to JSF2.0 and am trying to know what are the added features of the tags and am searching for the TLD docs for the html(h) and core(f) tags. By the way I have added a link for JSF1.2 for the same just in case how it looks, if I am not clear enough.

http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/tlddocs/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since JSF2 it's called VDL (View Declaration Language) instead of TLD (Tag Library Definition). You can find the JSF 2.0 Facelets VDL documentation here:

- [JSF 2.0 Facelets VDL documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/index.html)

Other JSF 2.0 documentation links are available [here](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/rlnotes/2.0.0/index.html).

- [JSF 2.0 API javadocs](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/javadocs/index.html)
- [Managedbean API javadocs](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/managed-bean-javadocs/index.html)
- [JavaScript API docs](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/jsdocs/index.html)
- [VDL docs for JSP](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/pdldocs/jsp/index.html)
- [HTML renderkit docs](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/renderkitdocs/index.html)

Comment: Thanks much. I didn't expect the answer to be this quick.